# I couldn't vote for the answers of my question?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Why can't I vote for the answers given for the question I have asked?
I am currently on 4 reputation because somebody down voted my last question. I have now lost 6 rep.

Your rule says I should have 15 rep to vote for an answer. How can I get 15 rep on this platform from this kind of ridiculous rules. Your current rules are beyond laughable.

Please reform your policies.

Comment: You have asked 6 questions on Super User so far. Gaining a **single** upvote combined. That indicates that the questions are not very good (otherwise, they would get upvotes, you would gain reputation and be able to upvote answers). Perhaps you should review your questions and improve them?

Comment: The system is ridiculous if you don't care about quality. If you do care about quality, it make much more sense.

Comment: I don't get why you have to support your proposal with statements like *"Your current rules are beyond laughable"*. How could anyone even remotely expect such a statement to work in favour of proposing the change of a rule that apparently has not been created out of thin air? As long as the tone makes the music such a proposal is just *bound* to fail, agreement or not. You apparently don't want a constructive rule change, so the question seems without any substance in the first place.

Comment: Nah, keep the policies, this idea is ridiculous

Answer (score 11):

You can *accept* an answer to any of your questions, noting the answer that helped you the most. You can then go back after getting 15 rep and vote on the others that you thought were useful.

I tend to agree that this is a little .. well, suboptimal, because it depends on humans remembering to go back and do things after an undetermined amount of time has passed. 15 rep isn't *that hard* to get once you learn the ropes, but I do appreciate your frustration.

We're considering the idea of *saving* your votes and then applying them *once* you get to 15 rep (up votes) or once you get to 125 rep (down votes), but there are some interesting challenges there (such as what would happen if you ran into a deficit since down-votes on answers cost 1 rep).

Totally blue-sky at this point, nothing more is happening beyond us talking about it, but it's something we'd like to make less frustrating. We tell people "Hey, you need to sign in to vote on this post", then they sign in, and they *still* can't vote - it drives people a little crazy.

The system as it currently is helps prevent gaming the system by growing 'sock puppet' accounts that are used to vote for one another systematically - that's why the restriction is there. We might have come up with a way to allow *mostly* unlocking the privilege much sooner, with safe guards still in place.

Comment: (and what if it made you go above your daily vote limit!)

Comment: Yeah, that, and many other potential quirks we've got to think about.

Comment: Now look, some body has edited my question wrongly ... and he is getting reputation (this is creating a fraudulent behavior through out the site). I am requesting question from another continent and this site provides answers almost instantly .Currently i am asking question about PC issues since i am a novice and i tried to vote the best answer according to me[ actually we are appreciating him] but we dont have the privilege ..